# Recovering/changing function name automatically in ROOT (C++) by CERN

Tags: c++, root-framework

Following is an example of a code, where I define (*line 1*) the name of the function to be used later (*line 4*).

```
char *funcname = "addition"; //line 1
void addition(){             //line 2
//file=Form("%s.txt",funcname);
TFile *ofile = new TFile(Form("%s.root",funcname) ,"RECREATE");//line 4 //EDIT
}
```

Now my question is: how can I use a similar code like `Form("%s",funcname)` to state the name of the function directly in *line 4* without requiring *line 1* by recovering the function name somehow, or change the *line 2* function name as in the example shown above?

For example, I was trying to alter my *line 2* code:

```
void Form("%s",funcname)(){
}
```

but technically that would mean this:

```
void "addition"(){
}
```

and not this:

```
void addition(){
}
```

I do not want the quotation marks. So what's the solution?

EDIT:
The above lines of code will be in a file named `addition.C` and it generates a file named `addition.root` by running the command `root addition.C` in the terminal.

I am trying to get an output using the code at *line 4* but with a different output file name every time I change the name of the function at *line 2*. This is so that I do not overwrite the output generated before when I ran the file with a different name giving me some output file.

Did I make the question clear enough? I thought this was a legitimate question and didn't expect so many downvotes in such a small time! Any suggestions to make more edits are welcome.

EDIT 2:
Changing function name dynamically is probably not possible as people suggested in comments. Then the solution should be to get the function name some way (automatically), someway like

`TFile *ofile= new TFile(Form("%s.root", __func__), "RECREATE"); //line 4`

but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: That doesn't look like a good idea. What problem are you trying to solve with the technique?

Comment: Function names are not a dynamic concept in those two languages. They mean nothing once the compiler is done. You could do some magic with macros or function pointers, but I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: Are you coding in C++ or C? It's not clear yet what you're trying to do, but most likely the best way to do it in C is totally different from the best way in C++.

Comment: Your understanding of C/C++ is incorrect, functions do not have literal names, I think what you want is a function pointer, that you can reassign to any function at runtime.

Comment: Are you trying to declare a function using a runtime defined name? or are you trying to call a function using a runtime defined name?

Comment: the code is actually a .C file to be used in ROOT by CERN

Comment: @MycrofD So this is a C file rather than c++ is it?  In any case this looks like an XY problem.  I think you should just describe what you're trying to achieve with this technique because it looks like it's going to be painful

Comment: I am guessing that maybe *function pointers* may be useful to you here? What are you trying to achieve overall?

Comment: @UKMonkey `.C` (capital letter) is typically a `C++` file extension (albeit not a good one imo).

Comment: everytime I need to change the function name i want to generate the corresponding output filename. Maybe i should make some edits to my question to make this clear as to what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @Galik well, that's just silly....

Comment: Possibly a `std::map` mapping a name to a function pointer/ function object? `std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> function_table;` ?

Comment: I tried making some changes. But I don't understand why there were so many downvotes. Can anyone help me understand where the question was not legitimate or not lucid. Or do I delete the question?

Comment: As far as I see you don't compile your `addition.C` (neither with a c++ compiler, nor through `root addition.C+`). In which case it is probably worth addressing a more root/cling specific help platform than stackoverflow. (like, whoever tries to answer your question should better know how the interpreter deals with the macro's filename). So please consider posting your question on the [root forum](https://root-forum.cern.ch)

Comment: @pseyfert yes, right. understood. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In C there is the standard predefined identifier `__func__` that holds the name of the current function.

```
file=Form("%s.txt", __func__); //line 4
```

should do the trick.

Since you also have tagged with C++, if I understand correctly since C++11 this will give you the mangled name of your function.

gcc has an extension `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` that gives you the demangled name together with the argument types.

Comment: Hi, I want to make changes to line 2 and not line 4; line 4 is working fine.

Comment: `Error: Symbol __func__ is not defined in current scope`
if I don't define `__func__` as in line 1. But if I define, it works just like `funcname`

Comment: As I said, it depends on the language and on the version. Older versions of gcc had `__FUNCTION__`, I think

Comment: ok so without pre-defining, I tried `__FUNCTION__` and also `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` . But it's the same error: not defined in current scope. May be I didn't understand you properly?

Comment: It seems that you have a old and non-conforming compiler. But since you didn't even tell us if you are doing C or C++, nor the platform, how should we know.

Comment: I am using ROOT by CERN. There my file is filename.C and I compile/run my file by `root filename.C` . The lines inside the filename.C contain c code as well as of c++. And ROOT is most definitely based on c++ codes. I am sorry, that's all I know.

Comment: if you just run with `root filename.C` the content goes through the interpreter, not the compiler. Is compilation with `root filename.C+` and option for you? (i.e. filename stays as it is w/o the `+`, you only add the `+` when opening the file with root)

Comment: @pseyfert hi. no,  `root filename.C+` exits with "Interpreter error recovered"

Comment: @JensGustedt I changed the topic from C,C++ to ROOT(C++).  And the suggestion you gave about `__func__` is recognised by syntax colouring in terminal. But `__FUNCTION__` isn't. So `__func__` probably should work but it doesn't. It says that it is *not defined in current scope* .

Comment: @MycrofD which root version are you using? related to Jens's comment, starting with root 6 the interpreter is C++11 standard conform. with root 5 that's a different story, as that part of root goes back to 1994 and thus predates c++98 (and wasn't meant to be fully c++ conform)

Comment: @pseyfert ROOT 5 it is.. v5.34.. so you say the answer is right for ROOT 6 ?

Comment: I only tried a 3 lined file `quicktest.C` and content `#include <iostream> \n void quicktest() { std::cout << __func__ << __FUNCTION__ << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}` and the output works fine with `root quicktest.C` and `root quicktest.C+`. That's not what you aim for in your line 2, but at least the three `__func__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` are defined in root 6 for me.